# Play/pause HTML audio doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html5-audio, background-music

I've implemented an html audio into my website with play/pause button via JS. Works perfect on all desktop and mobile devices apart from iOS.

This is not an autoplay, so I don't think it is braking any iOS policies?

This is a code I'm using.

P.S: tried searching on stackoverflow but found nothing that works.

```
<style>
 #demo {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    outline: none;
       }
</style>

<button onclick="Play()" id="demo"></button>

<audio id="player" preload="auto">
 <source src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/radmitry/Yoshio_Chino-We_Pray_For_Japan.mp3">
</audio>

<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById("player");
    audio.volume = 0.5;
    var butn = document.getElementById("demo");
    butn.style.background = "url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5acdf398c6f3e7252e9a31b9/5ad9f901d9a651ff58dad03b_play.svg) no-repeat";

    function Play() {
       if(audio.paused) {
               audio.play();
               butn.style.background = "url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5acdf398c6f3e7252e9a31b9/5ad9f8b88fb8e56097aa04ca_pause.svg) no-repeat";
    }

    else {
              audio.pause();
               butn.style.background = "url(https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5acdf398c6f3e7252e9a31b9/5ad9f901d9a651ff58dad03b_play.svg) no-repeat";
              }
      }

</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4pwwtewf/ I tried to play this on iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 11.2.6). Works well.

Comment: Hmm, can you try from here please? http://gilbert.webflow.io/

Comment: There is some delay before sound appears, however it works

Comment: Thanks. Really strange, tried on several iPhones and iPads in the store yesterday and no luck. I wonder if it is related to the blocked amazon's IP's, however background video is also located on Amazon and worked well.